# Accessing parameter and variable from a given agent onto Main

Tags: java, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

Trying to visualize the value of a variable and a parameter in a time plot from the agent "SteelMill" onto the "Main" Agent.

Cannot seem to access it through the SteelMill agent itself, and both the variable and parameter is both public.

Any possible solutions to this?

Check out screenshots for further problem statement:
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvhcd.png)

[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtWvk.png)

Comment: Can you please share the exact code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Use `steelMills.get(0).Inventory` on Main. This will access the first steel mill in your population on Main.

Please learn more about model structure and "[where am I and how do I get to](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fcode%2Faccess.html&resultof=%22%77%68%65%72%65%22%20%22%61%6D%22%20%22%69%22%20)" in the AnyLogic help.